# Excel Userform next button go to next row cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a set of data in 3x columns: Name, Age, Job.

I have put together a userform where a user can use to find Names, Ages and Jobs, in 3x separate textboxes (TextBox1, TextBox2 and TextBox3). It starts right at the top, which is done by design, which works fine. I also have a 'next' button, where when a user would click next and it will go to the next item in the list.

So when the user clicks next, it should ideally go to row 3 data (row 1 = headers).

Code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Dim AANo As String
    Dim AANa As String
    Dim AAEm As String
    Dim NextLR As Long

    NextLR = Sheets("AASD").Cells(Rows.count, "QH").End(xlUp).row

    For i = 2 To NextLR
        With Worksheets("AASD")
            Name = .Range(i, 8).Value
            Age = .Range(i, 9).Value
            Job = .Range(i, 10).Value
        End With

        TextBox1.Value = Name
        TextBox2.Value = Age
        TextBox3.Value = Job
    Next i

End Sub
```

This in theory should work, but it doesn't. I am not sure where I went wrong. Any advise where I went wrong?

Thanks

Modified code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Dim AANo As String
    Dim AANa As String
    Dim AAEm As String
    Dim NextLR As Long
    Dim count As Long
    NextLR = Sheets("AASD").Cells(Rows.count, "QH").End(xlUp).row
    count = 2
    For i = count To NextLR
        With Worksheets("AASD")
            AANo = .Range(i, 8).Value
            AAName = .Range(i, 9).Value
            AAEm = .Range(i, 10).Value
        End With

        TextBox1.Value = AANo
        TextBox2.Value = AANa
        TextBox3.Value = AAEm
        count = count + 1
        Exit For

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is never helpful. Your code loops through every row each time you press the button.

Comment: I have modified code, see edit. Still not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: Have you tried a global variable (*k*) and each time they click next, it adds 1 to k, up to the max k can be, then it resets to 3?

Comment: @Cyril - No I have not. I am not sure how to do that..

Comment: So what happens with the amended code? Of course each time you press he button you will start from the same place (i=2).

Comment: Could you work with combobox/listbox instead? Just add items when you open the userform. Then play around with listindex when button is clicked. As a user it would be great to be able to select from a list instead clicking through all rows.

Comment: @JvdV That was my first thought.  On initialize, set the combobox values.

Comment: From what I can see in your code - you press the `Next` button, the code should run a loop from 2nd to last row placing each value in variables as it goes and then transferring those values to the textboxes, but during the loop you tell it to `Exit For` so it will only ever show the value on row 2 (it will hit `Exit` on the first loop every time) - remove `Exit For` and it will only ever show the value on the last row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elaborate on my comment, somethign like:

```
Public k as Long

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Dim lr as Long
    with sheets("AASD")
        lr = .cells(.rows.count,8).end(xlup).row
        If k > lr OR k <3 then k = 3
        TextBox1.Value = .Cells(k, 8).Value
        TextBox2.Value = .Cells(k, 9).Value
        TextBox3.Value = .Cells(k, 10).Value
    end with
    k = k + 1
End Sub
```

---

If you go the route of a combobox for the values, you can set the combobox array during userform_initialize() using:

```
dim arr() as variant, lr as long
with sheets("AASD")
    lr = .cells(.rows.count,8).end(xlup).row
    arr = .range(.cells(3,8),.cells(lr,8)).Value
    UserForm1.ComboBox1.List = arr
end with
```

Comment: That is amazing. Thanks. One more question though - which I always find confusing - when using this code I get an Application-defined or object-defined error. When I amend the code (from .Range) to .Cells - it will work. Why?

Comment: @OdaySalim Whoops, my bad for not catching that sooner... pulled your code down and missed the syntax error.  Range("A2:A" & lr) versus Range(Cells(2,1),Cells(lr,1)) would be the two different syntax for the same range.

Answer (score 1):

Add another text box and keep it invisible and use it to count the number of times next is clicked.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

    Dim AANo As String
    Dim AANa As String
    Dim AAEm As String
    Dim NextLR As Long
    Dim counter As Long

    NextLR = Sheets("AASD").Cells(Rows.count, "QH").End(xlUp).row

    counter = me.counterBox + 1 'because on first time it will be empty

    With Worksheets("AASD")
        AANo = .Range(counter, 8).Value
        AAName = .Range(counter, 9).Value
        AAEm = .Range(counter, 10).Value
    End With

    TextBox1.Value = AANo
    TextBox2.Value = AANa
    TextBox3.Value = AAEm

    Me.counterBox = Iif(counter = NextLR, 0, counter)

End Sub
```